# Stove Knob adapter 8mm to 6mm?

Tags: stove

My stove takes 6mm stove knobs but I bought 8mm stove knobs.

Is there an adapter or something to make the 6mm shaft work with 8mm knobs?

Comment: What keeps the knob from spinning on the shaft? Is the shaft (and the hole in the new knob) D-shaped (see  https://www.surplussales.com/ShaftHardware/Knobs-16.html)?

Comment: @DanielGriscom Yes it is a D-Shaped shaft and hole.  Is there an adapter of sorts?

Comment: There probably is, but I wasn't able to find one.

Comment: Could you return those and buy the proper ones made for your stove? There are several sites on the Internet where you can plug in your model and brand information and it will tell you exactly what parts you need to buy.

Comment: @JasonHutchinson They're metal ones I got from China.  Wasn't worth the cost to ship them back.

Comment: just wondering if you managed to find the accessories?

Comment: @Daphne No, never found it.  Bought some of these http://a.co/3IDBEMz and used a knife to carve the outer layer to fit into the knob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapters like this actually do exist, but I have had a hard time tracking down the adapters by themselves. I have been able to find them packaged with replacement knobs, but am unsure if they will work with your particular one.

These sort of knobs are fairly inexpensive, and should fit your stove. They are available for electric and gas ranges.

[image: Universal Oven Knobs]

Comment: Where did you find that? I can't find any online.

Comment: They had these at my local hardware store. I also found them on Sears' online store.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find such an adaptor, but you may be able to make your own. Find a section of small copper pipe with 1mm thick walls, with ID greater than 6MM and OD greater than 8MM. Cut a length to match the D-shaped section of shaft, and then squash it to a tight fit around the shaft. You'll probably need to cut it along the length to reduce some of the circumference; do that on the side opposite the flat of the D (that's where the stress is). Then see if you can get the knob to be a straight fit. It will be iffy, and may not last, as indeed there will be a lot of stress on that flat.

Answer (score 0):

The inner part of my knob fell out and got lost.  I ended up wrapping a long strip of aluminum foil around the post with elmers glue to keep it from slipping. Had to add a bit of plumbers tape to get it snug.  It works!!